# What is the appropriate way to implement wobble/balance mechanics in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity, physics, game-mechanics

We are trying to implement a minigame where the player character sits on a bouncing ball, and needs to a) hit forward to move forward and b) hit left/right to adjust against the the ball's natural wobble (in other words, if the ball leans left, you must hit right).

We have tried implementing this by setting the bounciness and weight on the ball so that it bounces naturally when the player is not on it, then fixing the player model to the ball (in other words, treating them as a single unit), then having the CharacterController control the unit while it continues bouncing.

However, no matter how we tune the various factors (bounciness, weight, input multiplier, gravity), the ball remains quite sensitive and eventually spirals out of control. We would particularly like to allow the player *some* opportunity to regain control.

I have played a number of games that require some kind of reflex-based wobble/balance mechanic. Is there a general approach here that we are missing?

<sub>This question is for a small academic project, so we're wondering if there's a specific component we need, or part of the Physics engine we've missed, or technique we should look up - but please don't post code. There are no project requirements here except using Unity 3D (e.g. the assignment is not "implement a bouncing ball minigame").</sub>

Comment: Not sure if this will work as a plain physics system. What you might need to do is combine player and ball into an inverted pendulum system which, if necessary, breaks under certain conditions. If there is no time where player and ball will be separate, you might as well simulate them together.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pendulum

Comment: Maybe this will help illustrate my point: in the Tony Hawk games, a manual isn't simulated as player+board+ground. It's just player+ground, with the player in a special state that tracks "balance," possibly as an imaginary tangent vector or something.

Comment: @jzx we are treating them as a single object (I've clarified the question to make that clearer) - I think that link might be exactly what we're looking for! please post the inverted pendulum + imaginary balance approach as an answer and if it works for us I'll accept it! thanks for your insights

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to have is a [double pendulum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum) which is [inverted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pendulum).

[image: Figure 1]

Here, m2 is the player's center of mass. In order to remain in balance, L2 cannot be tangent to the ball (they would slip off) and m2 must remain nearly above f (otherwise they'd fall over). Obviously this would be complicated to manage in a game where you can't feel how you're balancing.

A simpler method is use a single leg pendulum and imagine where the player needs to direct their center of mass in order to move in that direction. To go forward, they need to shift their weight forward to stay on the ball. To stop going forward, they need to shift their weight back, otherwise their center of mass will keep going that way until they slip off.

[image: Figure 2]

I've used forward/backward momentum here since it's easier to describe, but the same principle applies to lateral movement and turning. In order to turn, they need to shift their weight counter to the direction of the turn while moving forward or backward.